# VB6 WebBrowser - Preencher campo de texto que tem máscara

Tags: visual-basic-6, navegador-de-internet

Olá,

Eu criei um programa em VB6 (eu sei que o VB6 é muito antigo, mas ainda funciona muito bem) que auxilia no preenchimento de dados em uma página utilizando o WebBrowser, e preciso que esse programa preencha parcialmente um campo de texto que tem uma máscara, mas ao definir o "value" a máscara não é acionada e aí se tentar digitar o restante dos dados o valor que o programa definiu é perdido.

Para que a máscara seja acionada é preciso chamar um evento desse campo, então eu gostaria de saber por gentileza como fazer o código abaixo em VB6:

```
var evento = new Event('input');
document.getElementById(idCampo).dispatchEvent(evento);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, no VB6 utilizei isso para chamar o evento de colar:

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById(idCampo).FireEvent "onpaste"
```